# "Error in plot.new()" when stacking two simple plots

Tags: r, plot, graph, par

I simply want to stack two simple line plots in base R. Here is what I tried:

```
x <- c(1:100)
y <- c(100:1)
old.par <- par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
plot(x, y)
plot(x, y)
par(old.par)
```

I used this method in the past successfully, but this time R throws me an error when I call `plot(x, y)`:
`Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large`. If I call `plot(x,y)` without `par(...)` beforehand, there is no error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error with the code you provided. Are you write to a specific output device? It sounds like the output is just too small to hold your plot.

Comment: How can I check if I write to a specific output device?

Comment: Did you call `pdf()` or something? Where are you trying to create this plot. Maybe run `dev.off()` a few times or restart R if things are goofed up.

Comment: I tried both things already, but it did not help.

Comment: Are you using RStudio? Your plot window might be too small.

Comment: @csgroen That's it!

Answer (score 0):

it's work for me [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg2Z4.png)

If you get this message in RStudio, clicking the 'broomstick' figure "Clear All Plots" in Plots tab and trying plot() again may work.